# How can I set disabled button style?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm making custom button styles, and I set the color but as:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#0000FF" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#00FF00" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But how can I set the disabled (IsEnabled=false) color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're changing that much stuff you should probably go ahead and do at the actual [Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709909.aspx) level but if you're looking just for that brush you can either change it in the dictionary or override it wherever you want by just exposing the resource like;

`<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="YourColor" />`

oh, and if you want to cut down some of your xaml footprint you can condense what you're doing like;

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0000FF" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#00FF00" />
</Style>
```

Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: Seems to be what I want, but it does not seem to care about me setting these keys. Iv added the <SolidColorBrush> below my button styles but it does not worked. Tested by setting the key to PhoneAccentColor and color to pink but no change. The same for PhoneForegroundColor and PhoneBackgroundColor that would have changed something....? Am I doing it in the wrong place?

Comment: Ya it depends on how you've got things. You just need it in a place where it will get inherited over the defaults. I forget where the default templates sit in WP but you can find them pretty quick/easy. You can change the defaults or if say you wanted to override them just at the instance level, you could declare your brushes in say the parent of where the controls sit like in UserControl.Resources or even closer in the tree if they're for example in a grid in its `<Grid.Resources>` but I'm hoping you've got it figured out if you've counted the answer as correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a visual state in Common visual state in your button style like this =>
Here, i set the background button proterty to red.

```
<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFF01919"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
```